# Insert a Row Only if a Row does not Exist

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2005

I am building a hit counter. I have an article directory and tracking unique visitors. When a visitor comes i insert the article id and their IP address in the database. First I check to see if the ip exists for the article id, if the ip does not exist I make the insert. This is two queries  -- is there a way to make this one query

Also, I am not using stored procedures I am using regular inline sql

Comment: This behavior is sometimes called an 'Upsert'. e.g. Update or Insert.

Comment: @Robert: I don't see that Luke is doing any updating.  It's just insert, or not.

Comment: I assumed they were keeping track of last visited. My mistake. In any event, IP addresses aren't good for tracking unique visits - e.g. NAT and DHCP

Answer (score 3):

Here are some options:

```
 INSERT IGNORE INTO `yourTable`
  SET `yourField` = 'yourValue',
  `yourOtherField` = 'yourOtherValue';
```

from MySQL reference manual: "If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted.".) If the record doesn't yet exist, it will be created.

Another option would be:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (yourfield,yourOtherField) VALUES ('yourValue','yourOtherValue')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE yourField = yourField;
```

Doesn't throw error or warning.

Comment: That's cool, but the user is using SQL Server 2005, as per his tag.

Comment: it looks like sql server tag was added after this answer was posted.

Comment: @Robert: That won't stop others from downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you create a UNIQUE constraint on the columns article_id and ip_address.  When you attempt to INSERT a duplicate the INSERT will be refused with an error.  Just answered the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634752/which-sqlite-statement-can-produce-a-result-to-indicate-duplicate-entries-androi/1634776#1634776) for SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MyTable where IPAddress...)
   INSERT...
```

Answer (score 1):

Not with SQL Server.  With T-SQL you have to check for the existence of a row, then use either INSERT or UPDATE as appropriate.

Another option is to try UPDATE first, and then examine the row count to see if there was a record updated.  If not, then INSERT.  Given a 50/50 chance of a row being there, you have executed a single query 50% of the time.

MySQL has a extension called [REPLACE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) that has the capability that you seek.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is execute dynamic SQL using the `SqlCommand` object.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM IPTable where IpAddr=<ipaddr>)
--Insert Statement
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Larry about using uniqueness, but I would implement it like this:

- `IP_ADDRESS`, pk
- `ARTICLE_ID`, pk, fk

This ensures that a record is unique hit.  Attempts to insert duplicates would get an error from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would really use procedures! :)

But either way, this will probably work:

Create a UNIQUE index for both the IP and article ID columns, the insert query will fail if they already exist, so technically it'll work!  (tested on mysql)

Comment: guess I got beat to it by Larry :)

Answer (score 0):

try this (it's a real kludge, but it should work...):

```
Insert TableName ([column list])
Select Distinct @PK, @valueA, @ValueB, etc. -- list all values to be inserted
From TableName
Where Not Exists 
    (Select * From TableName
     Where PK == @PK)
```